# Trying to install TA-lib

Tags: linux, debian, virtual-machine, ta-lib

I'm using gcp debian VM, and trying to install the module TA-lib doing this (with the tar already downloaded):

```
$ tar -xzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
$ cd ta-lib/
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr  DOING THIS I GET AN ERROR
$ make
$ sudo make install 
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

How can I solve?

Comment: `ta-lib`: No special requirements, is probably about a missing compiler → `apt install build-essential` ....... will install as dependencies { linux-libc-dev, libc6-dev } , i.e. things making `gcc` able to compile C code.

Comment: I had tried it yet E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

Comment: Well, please do `su -` and then enter the root password. ...... Then you can install "debian packages" with 'apt'.

Comment: I have a .deb package of ta-lib, if you are interested. Here is the link: https://file.io/yXz9wiY22e1K